# question about patent expiration

Tags: expiration

In reference to the patent: [US5829213](https://www.google.com/patents/US5829213)

How long is this patent in the U.S. and how do you know if it is still valid?

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky question since the patent laws changed that year

look it up here by patent number:

http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair

and learn about how long patents last here:

http://www.ipwatchdog.com/2014/07/26/how-long-does-a-patent-last/id=50534/

From the above reference:    "All utility and plant patents that were in force on June 8, 1995, or that issued on an application that was filed before June 8, 1995, have a term that is the greater of the “twenty-year term” or seventeen years from the patent grant."

I believe both numbers expire the patent.  5-1-2015 or 11-3-2015

If this was helpful please select it as an answer and or up-vote the answer.

Always seek a professional opinion on these matters.